# Distinct on Multiple columns of a pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a file

```
 (1,1,100)
   (1,1,200)
   (1,2,300)
```

Now I want the distinct to be applied on two columns and want the output to be

I did this

Group on all the other columns, project just the columns of interest into a bag, and then use FLATTEN to expand them out again:

```
A_unique =
    FOREACH (GROUP A BY id3) {
        b = A.(id1,id2);
        s = DISTINCT b;
        GENERATE FLATTEN(s);
    };

DUMP A_unique;
```

Output comes out to be

```
(1,1)
(1,1)
(1,2)
```

I expected it to be

```
(1,1)
(1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this should give you the desired output -

```
a = load 'sample1.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (id1:int, id2:int, id3:int);
b = group a by (id1, id2);
c = foreach b {
    first_e = limit a.id3 1;    
    generate flatten(group) as (id1, id2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code generates the required result.

```
a = load '$dir/data' using PigStorage(',') as (d1:int,d2:int,d3:int);
b= group a all;
c= foreach b {
d = a.(d1,d2);
e = DISTINCT d;
generate FLATTEN(e);
}
dump c ;
```

~